# Why does it work? Division algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a > b$. Then,

$\frac{a}{b} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor \frac{(a\cdot10^{k - 1} \mod b) \cdot 10}{b}\rfloor}{10^k}$.

This theorem is true. But, why? Assuming that it is, we can use this theorem to compute the (n+1)th-digit of $\frac{a}{b}$ as:

$\lfloor \frac{(a\cdot10^{n} \mod b) \cdot 10}{b}\rfloor$

Suppose I want to calculate the 55th digit of $\frac{227}{235}$. Then, I can just use the formula to calculate:

$\lfloor \frac{(227\cdot 10^{54} \mod 235)\cdot 10}{235} \rfloor$
$ = \lfloor \frac{1600}{235} \rfloor = 6$

Could someone explain why this is true?

Thanks

Comment: A cumbersome way to determine the $n$ th digit (after the decimal point) : Why not multiplying $\frac{a}{b}$ with $10^n$ and taking the integral part modulo $10$ ?